# Can I build a .net solution file for Mac Computer

Tags: c#, macos, solution

I am not sure that I am asking right question. But I have a suspicion that I can build a .net solution file for a mac computer. Please let me know if I can. Also the pros and cons.

Thanks

Comment: You can (see answers below) - but don't expect Mac users to like it and buy your app if native solutions are available.

Comment: A "solution file" is a Visual Studio file.  There is no version of VS that runs on Macs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono is one option, but depending on what parts of the .NET framework you need Silverlight might be an option as well. Mono is an open source project, which always has to chase Microsoft from behind, while Silverlight for Mac is a Microsoft release.

If you can live with the limitations of Silverlight, I'd definitely choose it instead of Mono. If you go the Mono way, be sure to test your application with Mono early and often, as there are incompatibilities.

Answer (score 3):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is probably your best bet for working with .NET on non-Windows platforms.

Pros

- Great support for the majority of .NET functionality
- Ability to build and run .NET apps on non-windows platforms

Cons

- Tooling is different (better or worse in different cases) than the Microsoft tools (e.g. MonoDevelop vs. Visual Studio)

Comment: Can I build the .net solution file from windows for a mac os ?

Comment: In general, yes. Check the [MoMa](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) tool for compatibility issues using the actual binaries from an existing project

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aOSX) on the Mac:

> Mono has supported MacOS X since
>   version 10.3 (Panther) and supports
>   both Intel and PowerPC based versions
>   with both 32 bits and 64 bits
>   configuration supported.
>
> You can use Mono on OSX to build
>   server, console and GUI applications.
>   Read below for the options available
>   for GUI application development.

Comment: Can I build the .net solution file from windows for a mac os  ?

Comment: You should be able to do that with MonoDevelop

Comment: Thanks it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's called Mono. http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page